# Let the div fill in the rest of my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created a header, body and footer for my html. Below is the code:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/o5rw4b82/2/)

```
JSFIDDLE
```

I have made my body (`#number`) to have a background of red color but it won't show up. I did not set the height of it and just set it to 100% because I just want it to fill into the middle of the page. Why is it the red background won't show up?

Comment: Classic problem. There are tons of examples in the Internet about making height of block 100%, check out. Disclaimer: the parent of the element should also have height defined.

Comment: [Check out this post about 100% height][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0):

If you won't add a min-height attribute in css like:

```
#numbers {
  min-height:30px;
}
```

or

```
<div id="numbers" style="min-height:30px" class="container-fluid"></div>
```

you can also think about adding a space in this div: see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o5rw4b82/3/)

or you add the background-color to your #holder

Comment: That doesn't make sense for most browsers. To have 100% height of an element, its parent should also have strictly defined height.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you have to set the height of all the parents of the div.
Add this css -

```
html, body, #holder {
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/o5rw4b82/6/

Comment: Why is it the red area overshot the footer?

Comment: @Coolguy because its `height` is 100% to the container, i.e. the `#holder`, to make it fit you should use this - `height: calc(100% - x)` where x is - heightOfYourTopNav(55px) plus `margin-top` or `padding-top` if any.

Answer (score 0):

```css
        #header {
          background-color: #273746;
          height: 55px;
          box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
        }
        #numbers {
          background-color: red;
          height: 83vh;
        }
        #keypad {
          height: 30px;
          background-color: springgreen;
          text-align: center;
          box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px 15px black;
        }
        .footer {
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          left: 0;
          bottom: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id="holder">
  <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar">
      <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></a>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Keypad <span id="counterId"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="numbers" class="container-fluid">

  </div>
  <footer class="footer">
    <div id="keypad" class="container-fluid">
      <a href="#keypad-toggle" id="keypad-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Number Pad
                </a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Comment: Set the height to 83vh? But then if different device will need different height?

Comment: sorry make it 100vh it will take the complete height of the remaining page

Answer (score 0):

You can do this nicely with flexbox

```css
#header{ background-color: #273746 ; height:55px; box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px;}
#numbers{background-color: red; flex-grow:1; }
#keypad{height:30px;background-color: springgreen; text-align: center; box-shadow: 15px 15px 15px 15px black;}
#holder {
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  flew-wrap:wrap;
  flex-direction:column;
}
body {
  margin:0;
  }
```

```html
      <div id="holder">
        <div id="header" class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar">
                <a href="#menu-toggle" id="menu-toggle" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></a>    
                <a class="navbar-brand">Keypad <span id="counterId"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="numbers" class="container-fluid">

        </div>
        <footer class="footer">
            <div id="keypad" class="container-fluid">
                <a href="#keypad-toggle" id="keypad-toggle"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></span> Number Pad
                </a>
            </div>
        </footer>
</div>
```